# Possible to cast to pointer of given type determined at runtime in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm fairly sure the answer to this is 'no, don't be stupid', but as they say, there are no stupid questions (only stupid people asking them).

I want to calculate the offset of an array. I have a `void *` handle to it and the `sizeof(element)`. I don't have an `x*` pointer (where `x` is the type of the element).

Is there any way I can cast the `void *` pointer to one of a given size so I can do pointer arithmetic based on that size? At the moment I'm casting to a `char *` (assuming a `char` is 1 byte*) and then multiplying the sizeof value by the offset. If I could somehow cast the pointer, then I could just use the array syntax, which would be cleaner.

As I say, I'm 99% sure this isn't possible and I'm basically asking for language-level type representation which C doesn't have. But worth an ask.

*And I'd rather not because it's not always true.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, that is guaranteed.

Comment: I read somewhere that it wasn't.

Comment: @Joe: it is guaranteed by the standard that it is.

Comment: @Joe: sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be one. What is not guaranteed is how many bits that is - it could be 16, or 7, or 9 rather than the 8 you might typically expect.

Comment: ... and many other places that say that it is

Comment: @Joe what's not guaranteed is that 1 stands for 1 byte. What _is_ guaranteed is that sizeof(char) is 1. Always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As several people have said in comments, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.  The relevant part of the C99 standard is in section 6.5.3.4, describing the `sizeof` operator:

> When applied to an operand that has
>   type `char`, `unsigned char`, or
>   `signed char`, (or a qualified version
>   thereof) the result [of the `sizeof`
>   operator] is 1.

This means that casting the `void *` to `char *` and adding `N * sizeof(element)` is correct and idiomatic.

(C is statically typed, so you can't cast to a type determined at runtime).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do introspection in C, but that doesn't prevent you from casting anything to anything.

```
void *v = whatever;
char *c = (char*)v;
c[0] = stuff;
element *e = (element*)v;
e[42].foo = bar;
```

If you want arbitrary size at runtime, then I don't believe there is a standardized way of doing it. Some compilers support:

```
char c[x];
```

where x is a variable, but I wouldn't trust it on all architectures.

You can definitely write a couple simple accessors for your pointers to at least separate out the pointer-math:

```
void* pointerAtPos( void*p, int offset, int width )
{
  return (void*)&( ((char*)p)[ offset * width ] );
}
```

Be careful of [address alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86).

Comment: Thanks. That last snippet is what I'm doing currently. Looks like it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

In C, casting is a compile time-only operation. As such, it isn't possible to determine the actual type of array element at run time.